# Is there any spell to bring back a disintegrated character?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-death, resurrection

In our latest session, one of our PCs got hit by a Disintegrate ray from an Undead Beholder. This dealt the exact damage needed, and so his character got disintegrated. Naturally, we are all sad that we lost a party member, but on top of that, my character was also *in love* with said PC, and, now heartbroken, will go to the edges of the earth to bring the PC back.

I'm aware of multiple spells that bring back characters from the dead (*Revivify*, *True Resurrection*, etc.); however, they all require either a body, or a part of the body.

Is there a *spell* that can bring back a disintegrated character? Or do I have to consult the DM for other options?

My character is a level 4 Druid; however, any spells will suffice, since I am willing to pay other people to cast the spell for me.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but I love when PC death motivates further action in the game, rather than grinding the narrative to a halt. Sounds like a fun group you have, there :)

Comment: @Vylix I'm not a monster expert, but it was just a scaled down version of an actual Beholder, with only 4 rays.You can find versions of it if you [Google '5e Undead Beholder'](https://www.google.com/search?q=5e+undead+beholder&rlz=1C1GCEU_enNL819NL820&oq=5e+undea&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j0l3.1759j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Vylix I'm guessing Jesse means a [Beholder Zombie](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/beholder-zombie), which fits the description of "scaled down version of an actual Beholder, with only 4 rays."

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## True Resurrection works

You mention that you have nothing of the body left. Well, that's not entirely true because you still have ashes, which most DMs would rule as being 'part of the body of the original character'.

But even if that wasn't the case, you can still use [*true resurrection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-resurrection) on them.

> The spell can even provide a new body if the original no longer exists, in which case you must speak the creature's name. The creature then appears in an unoccupied space you choose within 10 feet of you.

Simply casting [*resurrection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/resurrection) might not do the trick. It says it will 'restore any missing body parts', so perhaps your DM will be generous and say that if you bring some ash from the creature, everything else classifies as 'a missing body part', but *true resurrection* should work regardless of what you do or do not classify disintegrated ash as.

Comment: It seems to me that if you can use any amount of ashes to Resurrect a character, it's easy to clone a character this way aswell. Would make some fun roleplaying though!

Comment: Great! Now I just need 25,000gp worth of diamonds and holy water. This is going to be a great campaign

Comment: @JessedeBruijne Sounds like its time to switch to your back up character.

Comment: Just like in Paranoia where every PC has RAW five identical backup clones in storage which replace the PCs when they die.

Comment: @Eenzaat not really as you also need the character's soul to be free and willing to return.

Answer (score 28):

### Reincarnate

Ash remains obviously count as "piece of the body"

> You touch a dead humanoid or **a piece of a dead humanoid.** Provided that the creature has been dead no longer than 10 days, the spell forms a new adult body for it and then calls the soul to enter that body.

It is a 5th level spell, so it will be easier to find someone who can cast this than *true resurrection*. However, the target will have different body and face, and most likely entirely different race, something more than your character can brace, but that will likely make a good story for another time and place.

[Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/741460220078116864) implies that life-restoring spell that can replace body parts can indeed raise disintegrated creature by a beholder.

> **Q:** adventurer disintegrated by a beholder: can she get resurrect/raise/reincarnate?
>
> **A:** A life-restoring spell (like raise dead) that can't replace missing body parts can't raise the disintegrated.

**Note:** *reincarnate* cannot be used to bring back someone disintegrated by *disintegrate* spell, because the spell description specifically states the only way is:

> The creature can be restored to life only by means of a *true resurrection* or a *wish* spell.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88392/discussion-on-answer-by-vylix-is-there-any-spell-to-bring-back-a-disintegrated-c).

Answer (score 3):

### True Resurrection or wish spell

From PHB P. 233, Disintegrate:

> A disintegrated creature and everything it is wearing
> and carrying, except magic items, are reduced to a pile
> of fine gray dust. The creature can be restored to life
> only by means of a **true resurrection** or a **wish spell**.

The spell *Wish*, as I understand it, can resurrect any creature unless the DM minds (which is better left unsaid since nothing happens if the DM minds it). That includes dying from Beholder Rays. Besides, there are more powerful things than Beholders so adding that information in the Monster Manual is unnecessary.

Comment: Its self explanatory. Its also obvious that the ray is just the spell. There's no need for further explanation.